# Migrating MongoDB database into SQL Server through C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, mongodb, entity-framework

I am using the official MongoDB C# driver to create my MongoDB database using the code-first approach. I have the following entity, which holds reference to other entities as `ObjectId` (they are separate classes that inherit from `MongoEntity`):

Computers.cs

```
public class Computer : MongoEntity
{
    public ObjectId CpuId { get; set; }

    public ObjectId MotherboardId { get; set; }

    public ObjectId RamId { get; set; }

    public ObjectId PsuId { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

MongoEntity.cs

```
public class MongoEntity : IMongoEntity
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
}
```

I want to import the data programatically from the MongoDB database into SQL server using C#, while keeping the same one-to-many relation. So, my question is: how can I achieve something like this, and can I reuse my Mongo models with Entity Framework?

Comment: I don't really see why that wouldn't be possible. You'll need either an derived context for your other DbProvider or simply create an overload on the constructor which will use another connection string/provider, then Create the database matching your context, and then migrate data (that can be kinda tough though, you'll most likely have to query the tables and insert them into the newly created context, which can be pretty frustrating if you don't know what you're looking at)

Comment: Hi, @arnaudoff Although I haven't test it and I'm not sure it's useful for you, a 3rd party ADO.NET Provider for MongoDB is available for EF6. (https://www.rssbus.com/ado/mongodb/) If you have already try this, please disregard my comment.